# Pass an expression to be evaluated from Java to JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created a report with three parameters which are:

- name (a String with default value "World")
- money (an Double with default value 100)
- formatter (default value new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"))

I retrieve two records from database:

- "\"Hello \" + $P{name}"
- "\"I have \" + $P{formatter}.format($P{money}) + \" dollar\""

I pass these two records to JasperReport and expect to display

> Hello World
>   I have 100.00 dollar

However, the expressions are not evaluated and the output becomes this:

> "Hello " + $P{name}
>   "I have " + $P{formatter}.format($P{money}) + " dollar"

Since the record number is dynamic, I have to put them in Details band. The tricky part is that each record may have different parameters.

Is there any solution to make this idea works?

```
Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();

List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
records.add(new String[] { "\"Hello \" + $P{name}" });
records.add(new String[] { "\"I have \" + $P{formatter}.format($P{money}) + \" dollar\"" });

String[] columnNames = { "displayText" };

JRDataSource dataSource = new ListOfArrayDataSource(records, columnNames);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("test.jasper", parameter, dataSource);

JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
viewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JasperViewer.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
viewer.setVisible(true);
```

Report source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.4641000000000006"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["World"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="money" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[100]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="formatter" class="java.text.DecimalFormat" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<field name="displayText" class="java.lang.String"/>
<detail>
    <band height="20">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial Unicode MS"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{displayText}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: You want to calculate through java code or in ireport?

Comment: I want to calculate it in iReport.

Comment: I found there is no solution to do it in iReport. Do you have idea on evaluating it with Java code?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do looks a bit like internationalization, where you have messages containing placeholders and jasper reports fills them with expressions.

In your case, the text field could be changed to:

```
 <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[msg("Hello {0}", $P{name})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

And jasper reports will replace the `{0}` by the value of the `name` parameter.

Note that the message pattern itself can be a variable and that there can be unused placeholders with the `msg()` function. In your example, `{0}` will be bound to `$P{name}` and `{1}` to `$P{money}`:

```
List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
records.add(new String[] { "Hello {0}" });
records.add(new String[] { "I have {1} dollar" });
```

And:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[msg($F{displayText}, $P{name}, $P{money})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

More about i18n info [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html)

Comment: My situation is, the contents come from database. They will be fill in Details band and each records may have different parameters. The parameters needs to be evaluated during report generation.